# Mercurial commandline: How to show changes of a specific revision?

Tags: mercurial

After I pull a new head into my repository, I want to see what **files** are touched by the new head.  Like an `hg status` but without changing over to it.  I don't want the whole diff, just an overview.

Which I expect is a specific version of the more general question: how do i see a summary of the changes in a specific revision?

This is on the commandline, I don't want to fire up TortoiseHG or some other GUI.

Comment: related to the title: to see changes (the patch) that correspond to a given revision: `hg log --patch -r REV`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The status command shows you which files are changed. Use

```
hg status --rev .:tip
```

to compare the working copy parent revision (the currently checked out revision) with the tip revision.

If you've pulled more than one changeset, then this is different from

```
hg status --change tip
```

That command only shows the files touched by the `tip` changeset — not the combined changes between the currently checked out changeset (`.`) and `tip`.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `--change` option to [`hg status`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#status), passing it the revision you're curious about. For instance,

```
hg status --change tip
```

lists the files changed in `tip`. I believe this flag was added in hg 1.7.

Comment: Great! This also works for the hg diff, for example hg status --change 123

Answer (score 11):

Lol. Amazing how forcing myself to ask the question makes me realise where best to look.

```
hg diff -r11 --stat
```

The --stat seems to get me what I'm after.

Comment: Sometimes, you just have to think 'out loud' :) +1, you should accept this when the system allows you to do so.